# big integers with fixed length

Tags: c++, c, biginteger

I am looking for a library for big integers but with fixed width (128 or 256 would be enough). The reason is I don't want any allocation on the heap.
I tried to make them myself but implementing multiplication, division and modulo an efficient way seems to be quite a pain.

Does this already exists somewhere ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the GMP library: www.gmplib.org

Quoting from the function categories:

> Low-level positive-integer,
>   hard-to-use, very low overhead
>   functions are found in the mpn
>   category. No memory management is
>   performed; the caller must ensure
>   enough space is available for the
>   results. (...)

That seems to be what you need.

Comment: nice ! I am having a look on this

Answer (score 3):

This at least looks promising (hit number 8 for `int128 library` on Google).

http://www.mx-3.cz/tringi/www/langen.php?id=int128

"Unlike other large number classes, you can work with these just like with other P.O.D. types (for example store and load from files using fwrite/fread). Internal representation of these is correct 128-bit little-endian integer."

Answer (score 2):

If you find GMP too complicated for your taste, Dave Hanson  has some very nice functions in his book [*C Interfaces and Implementations*](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii).  There is a low-level interface that does no allocation (you control everything), and then there are two higher-level interfaces that manage progressively more allocation on the heap.

Comment: I made it work with gmp, but I'll have a look on this